"header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received UNKNOWN" '(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template'
When trying to send a Whatsapp API image template I get this error
'(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 132012,
error_data: {
messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
details: 'header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received UNKNOWN'
I read many similar error here on stack, but no one solution works, here's complete code, but still getting aforementionaed error.
Any advice on how to resolve this issue ?
await axios(
                  {
                    method: "POST",url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/${business_phone_number_id}/messages`, headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${GRAPH_API_TOKEN}`, 
                    ContentType: "application/json"}, 
                    data:
                    {
                      messaging_product: "whatsapp",type: "template",recipient_type: "individual",
                      to: 34xxxxxxxx7,
                      template:
                      {
                          name : "bienvenido_destinatario_nuevo_mensaje_imagen_es_es",
                          language: {code:"es_ES"},                                               
                          components:
                          [ 
                           {                                  
                             type: "header",
                             parameters:
                             [ 
                               { 
                                type: "image", image :{ link: "https://www.urlofimage.jpg"}
                               }
                             ],
                                                                                             
                             type: "body",
                             parameters:
                             [ 
                               { 
                                 type: "text",text : "some message"
                               }
                             ]
                                                              
                           }
                         ]                                                                         
                      },   
                    },                                  
                  }                             
               );


if using a only image template, so , without writing the body components, then it works ok, the issue is when using a image template that also contains text variable

RESOLVED !: missmatch in the code IT WAS ERROR , header and body parameters must be separated by brackets
